# Mirror Ubuntu desktop onto PS3 via wifi (DLNA etc)

Tags: screen, share, dlna, ps3

I'm looking to mirror my Ubuntu destop onto my TV by using my PS3. All done via wifi.
Similar to the 'AirPlay Mirroring' in Mac OS X Mountain Lion.
http://www.apple.com/macosx/mountain-lion/features.html#airplay

Is this possible? How would I go about it.
To be clear, I don't want to share movies in particular, rather to send my screen exactly as I see it.

Comment: Serviio has this functionality. I am fairly new to Linux/Ubuntu and I could not get it to work. But Serviio is the best DLNA server I have found for Windows or Ubuntu. Using Serviio from serviio.org and VLC player. Others have been able to do this with Serviio and Ubuntu. Good Luck, if you could figure out how to get it working and Layman's guide would help me out. Here is a link to their instructions: http://wiki.serviio.org/doku.php?id=stream_pc_linux

Comment: Hmm, I tried to set the VLC stream up as mentioned on the wiki and connect from the PS3 browser but no deal.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You simply want to share your screen to the PS3, without being able to interact with it from the PS3?

Comment: If you're lucky enough to have a PS3 with OtherOS and Linux installed, you might be able to use [Xpra](https://www.xpra.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at answers over the last five years (since the question was written) many say this is not possible:

- [How to use a Smart TV as second screen over wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/936423/how-to-use-a-smarttv-as-second-screen-over-wifi)
- [Ubuntu as Miracast Sender/receiver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318298/ubuntu-as-miracast-sender-receiver)

However a product called [PS3 Media Server](https://github.com/ps3mediaserver/ps3mediaserver) has support for Linux using a Play Station 3 and might work. Be forewarned it hasn't been maintained since 2016.