# Is it possible to extend the desktop without hooking up a second monitor?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have a Microsoft Surface RT tablet that I want to use as a second monitor for my Ubuntu laptop using Splashtop Remote Desktop as in this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldb0RvmXzsA

So far, I can get the tablet to mirror the display on my laptop, but not to extend it.

I think it could work in theory, if only I could trick the laptop into creating a second "virtual" desktop, even though I don't have a second monitor hooked up. There seems to be a feature for this in Windows, but is there a way to do it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try going to your 'Displays' from the GNOME launcher, there should maybe a button saying 'Detect Displays' then you should have some options like 'Mirror Display', simply check or uncheck this. The settings may vary from distribution to distribution. I am not 100% sure if this will work as I am not familiar with the software suite you are using. You might need to use something like Intel WiDi. It might be a worth a try!

[image: Picture]

Intel WiDi Reference:
[Using Intel Wireless Display (WiDi) in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341907/using-intel-wireless-display-widi-in-ubuntu)

Comment: "Maybe" and "I am not 100% sure". Is this a good answer?