# Google cast on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google, chromecast

I've gotten Google cast to run from Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04
but only the Chrome window is shown on the TV.  From my Android tablet
I can display anything that displays on the tablet on the TV.
(btw this is done by:
Settings> Display> Wireless display>

Can any Ubuntu window be cast to the TV?

Comment: The easiest way to display the computer screen on a TV is to connect the two with an HDMI cable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Intel Wireless Display (WiDi) in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/341907/using-intel-wireless-display-widi-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, but the UI is not particularly obvious. Click the down arrow to the right of "Cast to" and click "Cast desktop". Later when you start the cast you get a choice of any application window or entire desktop.

[image]

Comment: This works very well, but with one limitation: it duplicates the desktop. I think you cannot cast an Ubuntu window while seeing something else on your PC, which would be analogous to casting a Chrome tab.

Comment: Google Cast has been removed from Chrome store. What is it's alternative?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Google Cast web store description](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) (emphasis added):

> The Google Cast extension enables you to find and play content on your Chromecast device *from your Chrome browser*.
>
> […] using your computer as a remote to *browse* for videos and to control playback.
>
> You can also cast any of your tabs in Chrome to your TV, letting you enjoy sites, photos, or even video from the best screen in your home. […]

Since there's no mention of the computer desktop or other applications I'd say that Google Cast cannot be used as a general remote desktop interface.

<s>There are however other applications for such a purpose, most notably</s>

- [VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC) if you want to display or remote-control arbitrary desktop applications (though it wouldn't work well for video and audio content), and
- [XMBC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XBMC) if you want to play back media from your Ubuntu machine on an Android device.

Both need a server software on the Ubuntu “host” system and a suitable client on the Android “client” (of which there are many).

Comment: @user68186: Thanks. I clarified my answer to say that VNC can be used to just share a view on the desktop over the network without the option of remote control.

Comment: The client side is Chromecast attached to a TV, not an Android tablet. There are no VNC client for Chromecast!

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that Chromecast devices run a regular Android system.

Comment: I have one and it does not.

Comment: The answer by Duncan Harris appears to mean that it can be done (I have tested it and it works).

Comment: Google Cast has been removed from Chrome store. What is it's alternative?

Comment: @SunBear: I don’t know. Could you please 1) [post a bounty](/help/bounty) on this question with a suitable request or 2) open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I've been using,[at least for video] is to right click on the video in nautilus, select "open with", and choose Google Chrome. When the video opens, in the top right corner of the browser window, select the menu, scroll down and select "cast" then select your preferred device...