# How do I cast my Android screen to my Ubuntu HTPC?

Tags: android, kodi, screencast, chromecast

I have an Android phone running 5.0 (CM12) that has "cast screen" on the quick settings page, but no devices are listed. I don't own a Chromecast, but I have an Ubuntu HTPC running 14.04 and Kodi.

What can I do to make the HTPC a receiver and show up on the network?

Comment: check also my questions and answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/318298/ubuntu-as-miracast-sender-receiver

Answer (score 1):

Currently, i am finding a way to perform the casting operation by the default cast screen button given in the drop down menu for android 4.4 above(most probably). But there is another way using software and apps available in the Google Play Store.

1. All Cast Receiver
2. Vysor

In both of these cases its as simple as installing the android app on your android device and adding the extension for the corresponding app installed and then just launch the extension and connect to the available network available from your android device. Note-> Both These extensions are for Chrome.

Check this list: http://www.topalternativeto.com/vysor

If you are still having problems with getting started just Google the application names and you would find someone making money with your required video on youtube.

Comment: indeed, Vysor works well out of the box (Chrome only) with basic features and resolution. If you need better resolution you need to subscribe see http://www.vysor.io/#pricing

Comment: the link is broken can you please fix it @Arunava

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the use of AllCast Receiver for Chrome and Mirror on your Android phone.

1. Download Allcast Receiver for Chrome.
2. Download Mirror for Android.
3. Make sure your computer and smartphone are on the same WiFi network.
4. Start AllCast Receiver through the Chrome App Launcher.
5. Start Mirror on your Android phone.
6. In Mirror, choose the Network Device that matches your PC. It will still start with "Chrome @" followed by an IP address.

Solution grabbed from: [makeuseof.com](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mirror-android-screen-pc-mac-without-root/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers above, you can't try using an Apple AirPlay [sender app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=AirPlay&c=apps) in conjunction with Shairport-sync, which is available from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~dantheperson/+archive/ubuntu/shairplay-sync). Just do

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dantheperson/shairplay-sync
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install shairport-sync
```

to install it. I personally have not tried it out,  tu it looks promising. If you just want to cast from the YouTube app or Google Play Music, there are a few older Google Cast receivers you can try. For instance, if you have Chromium or a derivative you can try [CR Cast](https://github.com/jloutsenhizer/CR-Cast), which while no longer on the Chrome Web Store, still works happily on my Raspberry Pi. You will need to download as a zip and lad in the extension manually though. You can also try [Nodecast](https://github.com/mauimauer/nodecast) which runs on NodeJS. You'll need to run it as root for it to work right. Just note that the previous two options don't support full screen mirroring, just YouTube.