# Wireless screen mirroring

Tags: wireless, screen

How can I mirror the screen to a smart TV from Ubuntu ?

Comment: similar question discussed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318298/ubuntu-as-miracast-sender-receiver) check it.

Comment: Depends on the type of smart TV.