# How can I cast my screen on to lg tv

Tags: screencast, smart-tv

I want to know how can I cast my screen on to my lg tv wirelessly I have a WiFi please help

Comment: Did you read the [LG website](https://www.lg.com/uk/support/solutions/tv/smartshare-screen-share) on this ? It says: `Linux: There is an open source project called OpenWFD.`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu as Miracast Sender/receiver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318298/ubuntu-as-miracast-sender-receiver)