# Ubuntu Miracast applications if any?

Tags: 16.04, wifi-direct

Hello guys is there any application which has the same functionalities of Miracle-cast on Ubuntu, even if its not open-source i would like to know as i wanted it on my Ubuntu 16.04 platform.

"NOTE: [Ubuntu as Miracast Sender/receiver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318298/ubuntu-as-miracast-sender-receiver)"
I did check the above link, but was not able to conclude that its not available on Ubuntu.
TIA