# Miracast on Ubuntu mate 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display, ubuntu-mate, streaming

Does anybody know how i can use miracast on ubuntu mate 20.04 to stream from my laptop to my smart tv.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu as Miracast Sender/receiver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318298/ubuntu-as-miracast-sender-receiver) Please try all the solutions and if they don't work, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1260596/edit) and add information about what you tried and why they didn't work, including error messages, if any. If you use commands in the terminal, copy and paste the error outputs from the terminal directly into your question above. Then format the output as `code` using the { } icon above the edit window.